# Fetch email address, content and attachment using pop - ruby script

Tags: ruby, email

I have using ruby 1.8.7. I have try to fetch mail from inbox.

```
require 'net/pop'
Net::POP3.enable_ssl(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
Net::POP3.start('pop.gmail.com', 995, 'user@gmail.com', 'password') do |pop|
  if pop.mails.empty?
    puts 'No mails.'
  else
     pop.each_mail do |m|   # or "pop.mails.each ..."
     puts "Mail #{m.header}"
     end
  end
end
```

It is working fine. here how to i get mail address, subject and attachment from "m.header"?

Comment: what is 995? asked out of curiosity

Comment: Not sure and can't test right now, so a comment instead of an answer: You need to `.pop` the mail to get a `POP3Mail` object, from which I think you can read your desired information.

Comment: @ArupRakshit it is connection port.

Answer (score 0):

@madasamysankarapandian You cannot extract info directly from **m.header** as it is a String class. You will have to parse it.

Comment: Thanks @JunaidKirkire, Is there any easy way to parse from m.header?.

Comment: @MadasamySankarapandian You can use Regex for this.